# Making a scalable C# websocket server(multiple clients)

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket

I need some advice or more information on how to handle high number of socket connections. Here is a overview of my program.

Open a socket on a defined port and listen for incoming connections. Then call  beginaccept with Asynccallback. Accept the connection, get the headers, hash and encode the key and send a response thus completing the handshake.

After handshake is complete, the socket is passed to an ArrayList. I call Spcket.Select to listen for any incoming messages and invoke a socket.Receive when data is sent from client.

Now I wish to scale this to process hundreds of messages. Keeping an Arraylist is not the best I believe.

You input is greatly appreciated. Let me know if you wish to see the code.

Comment: Have you done any measurements?

Comment: Do you also need to write your own? SignalR Core uses websockets and has server and client side libraries.

Comment: no I have not done any measurements yet.

Comment: I have looked into SignalR briefly. my requirements are strictly websockets as I need to develop a service based on sockets.

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft documentation. socket.select accepts an IList parameter to check the state of a socket for readability, writablity. I was unable to find a work around.

Also sockets are object which cannot be easily stored in databases. Therefore, at current time, my conclusion is to keep all the active sockets in a list and update it as connection come and go.